# JavaScript: Logical Comparison fails when values have different decimal places

Tags: javascript, html, validation, var

The code below is the beginning of a program that will allow the user to input values and the computer will guess the values. I'm stuck on my input validation. For some reason my input validation passes when I compare numbers with the same decimal places, such as 25 and 49.

[Image of passed input validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXmPp.png)

However, when I try to compare something like 9 and 25, although the input validation should allow it through, it goes to the else portion of my code. I assume this has something to do with the way JavaScript is interpreting the data type. The code is a bit messy and the program is not complete. The focus is just on the way I'm pulling the values from the HTML and the input validation now. Here's the code.

```
function runGame() {
    //get variables from the input fields in HTML form
    var low = document.getElementById('lowNum').value;
    var high = document.getElementById('highNum').value;
    var guess = document.getElementById('compGuess').value;

    //input validation
    if (low < high && low > 0 && high <= 50 && guess > 0 && guess <= 10) {
        alert("Low number: " + low + "\nHigh Number: " + high + "\nComputer Guesses: " + guess);
        document.getElementById("computerGuessVal").innerHTML = getRndInteger(low, high);
    } else {
        alert("Invalid selection. Make sure that the number range is between 1 and 50 and guesses are higher than zero.");
    }
}

function getRndInteger(low, high) {
    high = Math.floor(high);
    low = Math.ceil(low);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low;
}
```

Comment: console.log the params to check the data type and use parseInt or parseFloat to make them the correct type

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. Your function ends before the "else" because of the second closing bracket.

Comment: Also your code is extremely difficult to read because of inconsistent indentation and unnecessary extra white space. (I have now edited the question to address the syntax error and the indentation and white space. Please try to format your questions more nicely in the future.)

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your if condition and debug, there check which condition is failing due to which control is going in else block

Comment: I apologize for the messy code @AmericanUmlaut. I attempted to clean it up a bit before posting and must have messed up the brackets. This is my first post and the code snippet function wasn't particularly helpful.  The function did have proper closing braces before. I'll attempt to see if I can get the data type sorted out using LordNeo's solution. If that doesn't work I'll try debugging. Thanks.

Comment: Don't put an answer in your question. Instead, post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - Solved I added ParseInt to my code after checking the data types

with alert(typeof guess). Here's the working code:

//get variables from the input fields in HTML form and convert to integer

var low = parseInt(document.getElementById('lowNum').value);

var high = parseInt(document.getElementById('highNum').value);

var guess = parseInt(document.getElementById('compGuess').value);

Thanks for the suggestions!